# Find most common randomly assigned string in ArrayList

Tags: java, probability

I am working on a simulator in which Person objects (stored in an ArrayList) "reproduce" and make babies, and they inherit "genes", represented as 4-letter strings. At the program start, the gene pool for the first people is randomly generated.

At every tick of the timer, I want to calculate what the most common "gene" among all the Person objects is.

The four letters are:
1. G, Z, N, F 
2. A, T, C, G 
3. B, F, Q, N 
4. A, C, T, E

There are 256 possible combinations in this case, and there has to be a more efficient check than 256 if-else statements.

The Person class (minus get/set methods)

```
public class Person {
    static Random rand = new Random();
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;
    private String genes;
    private char sex;
    private int age, numKids;

    public Person() {
        mother = null;
        father = null;
        genes = createGenes();
        if (rand.nextDouble() <= 0.5)
            sex = 'm';
        else
            sex = 'f';
        age = 18;
        numKids = 0;
    }

    public Person(Person m, Person f) {
        mother = m;
        father = f;
        genes = inheritGenes(m, f);
        if (rand.nextDouble() <= 0.5)
            sex = 'm';
        else
            sex = 'f';
        age = 0;
    }
//create genes for original Persons
    private String createGenes() {
        String genetics = "";

        double first = rand.nextDouble();
        double second = rand.nextDouble();
        double third = rand.nextDouble();
        double fourth = rand.nextDouble();

        if (first <= 0.25)
            genetics += "G";
        else if (first <= 0.68)
            genetics += "Z";
        else if (first <= 0.9)
            genetics += "N";
        else
            genetics += "F";

        if (second <= 0.65)
            genetics += "A";
        else if (second <= 0.79)
            genetics += "T";
        else if (second <= 0.85)
            genetics += "C";
        else
            genetics += "G";

        if (third <= 0.64)
            genetics += "B";
        else if (third <= 0.95)
            genetics += "F";
        else if (third <= 0.98)
            genetics += "Q";
        else
            genetics += "N";

        if (fourth <= 0.37)
            genetics += "A";
        else if (fourth <= 0.58)
            genetics += "C";
        else if (fourth <= 0.63)
            genetics += "T";
        else
            genetics += "E";
        return genetics;

    }
//inherit genes from parents for new Persons
    public String inheritGenes(Person m, Person f) {
        String genetics = "";
        double first = rand.nextDouble();
        double second = rand.nextDouble();
        double third = rand.nextDouble();
        double fourth = rand.nextDouble();

        if (first < 0.5) {
            genetics += m.getGenes().charAt(0);
        } else
            genetics += f.getGenes().charAt(0);

        if (second < 0.5) {
            genetics += m.getGenes().charAt(1);
        } else
            genetics += f.getGenes().charAt(1);

        if (third < 0.5) {
            genetics += m.getGenes().charAt(2);
        } else
            genetics += f.getGenes().charAt(2);

        if (fourth < 0.5) {
            genetics += m.getGenes().charAt(3);
        } else
            genetics += f.getGenes().charAt(3);

        return genetics;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how your class `Person` looks like?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the concrete problem you're facing? Where is the code you tried?

Comment: Also, if you want help, besides posting your attempt, you really need to be clearer about what your inputs are, with examples, and what your output should be, with an example. I can't understand it when you say "The four letters are:", and what follows is a list of 4 sequences containing a total of 11 distinct letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code that finds the most common gene from a `List<Person>`. I just added a getter for the `genes` `String`:

```
String getGenes() {
    return genes;
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    people.add(new Person()); // 100 random genes
}

String mostCommonGene = people.stream()
                .map(Person::getGenes)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .get()
                .getKey();

    System.out.println("Most common gene: " + mostCommonGene);
```

We use Java 8 Streams:

- we get the `stream()` of `people` list.
- we `map()` (transform) every `Person` to `String` - their `genes`.
- we `collect()` the *stream of genes* with `groupingBy()` fed by `Function.identity()` and `Collectors.counting()`. This step produces a `Map<String, Long>` which represents a *map* of `genes` and their frequencies. Effectively, this counts the occurrences of the genes from `people` list.
- then we call `entrySet()` on that map and then `stream()` again - now we have a *stream* of *map entries* (you can think of them as pairs - the gene and its frequency inside one object. Convenient).
- we call `max()` to find the *entry* with the highest *value* (interpreted as frequency). `Comparator.comparingLong()` tells the `max()` algorithm how we compare the pairs, but the *pairs* are not *long*s - that's why we have to tell it how to convert the *entry* to a `long` - we get the *value* of that *entry*.
- then we call `get()`, since `max()` returns an `Optional<T>`. We just want the `T` (the *entry*).
- lastly, we call `getKey()` on the *entry* that represents a pair of the most frequent gene and its frequency. A key is the gene and the value is its frequency, as previously mentioned.

---

If you are unfamiliar with most concepts described in this answer, I highly suggest you learning about **Java 8 Streams**. Once you get used to them, you can't stop.

Comment: This worked well, thanks! I am unfamiliar with streams, and I appreciate the point in right direction!

Comment: No problem! If you wish to print the frequencies of all the genes in a somewhat friendly manner, you can always stop on the map creation: `System.out.println(people.stream().map(Person::getGenes)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())));`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use scenario it could be more efficient to use additional `Map<String,Long>` as counter for each gene (increase counter for each new Person gene).

Such approach will use a bit more memory (`Map<String,Long>` with up to 256 elements) and new Person construction will be a bit slower (update of the Map), but getting the most common gene on each tick could be considerable faster if there are many Person objects alive as these are already grouped and counted in the Map, so only up to 256 entries should be compared.